# Отмена последнего действия (кодировки) Notepad++

Tags: перекодировка, notepad++

Всем привет. Возникла небольшая проблема при смене кодировки. Был php код с кучей разных символов в кодировке utf-8. Я случайно нажал преобразовать в ANSI. На месте некоторых символов появились знаки вопроса, что в общем-то логично. Поняв, что допустил ошибку, решил отменить последнее действие, но не получилось (кнопка "Отмена" неактивна). Обратное преобразование в UTF-8 также проблему не решает, сохраняются знаки вопроса, что опять же логично. Никто не в курсе, можно как-нибудь отменить преобразование кодировки, а то как-то совсем не гуд без такой функции?

Answer (score 1):

Закрыть без сохранения и открыть ещё раз. И делать наконец резервные копии файлов.

Вкратце - convert функция однонаправленная, как макросы в Excel, и так как сложно/невозможно отследить то, что макрос делает с данными, его действие в историю не пишется, и как результат, история очищается, так как перестает быть когерентной.

Comment: Закрыть без сохранения и открыть ещё раз - не помогает, остаются знаки вопроса

Comment: Значит, доставайте из бэкапа. Нет бэкапа - переписывайте весь текст.